# How do I add characters like @, /, \, * in a string in Python, without it reading it as an escape sequence

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to send a message on twilio. The message includes an ASCII artwork that I have made. It contains characters like *, /, \, " and #. When I add my drawing in a python string, it reads it as an escape sequence, giving me a bunch of unintended errors. How do I reformat my code so that python prints anything that is within the strings as is, without trying to edit it as an escape sequence.

```
message = client.messages.create(
                     body= """                  


      .---------. | == |
      |.-"""""-.| |----|
      ||       || | == |
      ||       || |----|
      |'-.....-'| |::::|
      `"")---(""` |___.|
     /:::::::::::\" _  "
    /:::=======:::\`\`\
jgs `"""""""""""""`  '-'


                     """
```

Comment: Escape them with `\\`

Comment: Use `'\'` to escape characters

Comment: Also you can have raw multi line strings `r"""..."""`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You can post your comment as an answer. It seems to be the correct solution required by OP.

Comment: you can save artwork to .txt file and read it

Answer (score 1):

`s="\\"` is a single backslash. You escape escaping.

When copy-pasting, use replace command in your editor (Ctrl+H)